# What file system is my file on?

Tags: filesystems, files, mount

How do I figure out which file system a given file/directory is located on?

(For example, I would like to know if the file/directory is a temporary file in RAM, or if it's stored on disk. And what mount point it corresponds to, if any. Etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`df <path>` should do what you want on nearly all systems.  It displays the file system and the mount point, along with the space usage statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command `mount` or `cat /etc/mtab`.