# What disk is a file / directory stored on?

Tags: filesystems, files, block-device

From the command line (bash) I would like to know what disk a given file is stored in. E.G.:

```
$ [what filesystem is this file in command] /tmp/example/file

/dev/sda1
```

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27271/what-file-system-is-my-file-on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the answer by using `df` command on the directory containing the executable.  For example, on you example, you could say

```
df /tmp/example
```

Comment: @don_crissti my `df` (GNU coreutils 8.13) does not have that option: `df: unrecognized option '--output=source'`.